# Dagger superscript in Latex

Tags: symbols

I would like to attach a dagger symbol (\textdagger) as a superscript in front of a word (not in math). How can I do it?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `\textsuperscript`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello\textsuperscript{\textdagger} world.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or (big thanks to barbara beeton!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello {}\textsuperscript{\textdagger}world.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Er, the question says *in front* of a word.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! I did not read carefully...

Comment: What's `{}` for?

Comment: @egreg [Someone recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530700/how-to-cancel-powered-number#comment1341978_530700) "in doubt, use braces". ;-) The analogous syntax works in math mode, so is easier to remember.