# How to cancel powered number?

Tags: cancel

[image]

How to get the result circled in red? I tried `3^\cancel{4}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Superscripts should be braced: `3^{4}` and 3^{\cancel{4}}`. It's true that `3^4` works, but you need to know the precise rules of TeX to understand why. In doubt, use braces.

Comment: Oh, I have used it before but i had forgotten it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not to use [`cancel`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cancel/cancel.pdf) package and to adopt the simple negation `\not`. Here there is a small example with a screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
$3^4$, $3^{\not 4}$, $3^{\cancel{4}}$
\end{document}
```

Excellent, after, the comment of @egreg.